# How do I return True if a string in a cell is contained anywhere in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting

I am working in google sheets. Excel also works.

---

I have column called "funds." This column has names of venture funds, such as Accel, A16z, and Sequoia. One fund in each row.

I have another column called "funds2." This column also has names of venture funds, such as Accel, A16z, and Sequoia. The difference is that this column has multiple funds in each row. So each row looks like this: "Accel, Sequoia, A16z." Another row might have "Greylock, Primary Ventures, Union Square Ventures" and so on.

How do I write a formula to flag cases if any fund name in the column "funds" is found anywhere in "funds2" column?

Much thanks!

Comment: Can you should us the specific structure by adding it to your question?  Also, what version of Excel can we assume you're working with if it's not Google Sheets?

Comment: Also, do you mean you want to know if any given fund is mentioned within funds2 for that specific row, or across *all* rows in funds2

Comment: Use any one tag. Please ! If you are working with `Excel` then use excel or else `Google Sheets` refer below in answers @zitiaa has posted. That should help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you can simply use `COUNTIF` with wildcards.

Assuming 'funds' is in A2:A and 'funds2' is in B2:B, you can try the following formula in row 2 of an empty column:

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(fund,IF(fund="",,0<COUNTIF(B2:B,"*"&fund&"*"))))
```